# Proper argument for dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

"In the vector space $\mathbb{R}^5$ a given sub space $U_1=span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ where $v_1=(1,1,0,1,1), v_2=(1,3,2,1,3), v_3=(0,6,7,0,4)$

Show that $dim(U_1)=3$
"

So, I know that the dimension of $U_1$ must be 3 since it is spanned by 3 vectors, but how can I show it?

Comment: To show that the dimension is $3$, you have to show that the three vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: @KittyL Thanks - Makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method is to first put the vectors as rows of a matrix.

$${\bf V} = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 4
\end{array}\right)$$

Then perform [row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Row_operations) to put the matrix ${\bf V}$ into [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

Once in row echelon form, the number of non-zero rows gives the rank of the matrix.

**This is the same as the dimension of the space spanned by the rows.**

---

Performing the row operations $R_2-R_1$ **and then** $R_3-3R_2$ on the matrix ${\bf V}$ gives

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2
\end{array}\right)$$

There are three, non-zero rows, so the rank of ${\bf V}$ was three, and so the row of ${\bf V}$ span a three-dimensional space. If three vectors span a three-dimensional space then they are linearly independent.